# Field exists (_exists_) query in Kibana does not return any results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

This query works great from Kibana's Console:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "_exists_:my.field"
        }
    }
}
```

However if I search for `_exists_:my.field` in the Lucene search box on the Discover tab, I get no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either:

1. Disable the [new search syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.7/kuery-query.html) and revert to Lucene syntax, where this query works. This is under the "Options" button at the far right of the search field.
2. Use the new syntax, where the query is instead `my.field:*`.